# Error expected class-name before ‘{’ token C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, include

I keep getting this error while trying to compile my project,
but I have no idea why.
In addition I'm getting

> "error: ‘CrewMember’ has not been declared"
>   for a class method, and the error "expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token"

I'm pretty sure the problem is about putting the right "include" but can't put my finger on it

This is my code:

```
#ifndef SMALLTOBIGIDSORTER_H_
#define SMALLTOBIGIDSORTER_H_
#include "CrewSorter.h"
#include "CrewMember.h"

//this is the line where i get the error
class SmallToBigIdSorter: public CrewSorter {
public:
    SmallToBigIdSorter();
    ~SmallToBigIdSorter();
    //this is where i'm getting the second error error: ‘CrewMember’ has not been declared
    bool compare(CrewMember* member1, CrewMember* member2);
};

#endif /* SMALLTOBIGIDSORTER_H_ */
```

CrewSorter class:

```
#ifndef CREWSORTER_H_
#define CREWSORTER_H_
#include "CrewMember.h"
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class CrewSorter {
public:
    CrewSorter();
    virtual ~CrewSorter();
//expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
    void addCrewMember(vector<CrewMember*>* membersList, CrewMember* newMember);
    void removeCrewMember(vector<CrewMember*>* membersList, int id);
    void sortCrewList(vector<CrewMember*>* membersList);
    virtual bool compare(CrewMember* member1, CrewMember* member2);
};

#endif /* CREWSORTER_H_ */
```

CrewMember class:

```
#ifndef CREWMEMBER_H_
#define CREWMEMBER_H_
#include "Movie.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
class Movie;
class CrewMember {
protected:
    string name;
    int id;
    int age;
    char gender;
    int moviesNumber;
    vector<Movie*>* movies;
    string jobDescription;

public:

    /*
    * the function will print a string representing the
    * employee unique string
    */
    virtual void print(std::ostream& str) const = 0;
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const CrewMember& crewMember);

    /*
    *  the function will add the given movie
    * to the crew member
    */
    void addMovie(Movie* newMovie);

    /*
    *  the function will remove the given movie
    * from the crew member
    */
    void removeMovie(string movieId);

    vector<Movie*> copyMovieList();

    bool movieExists(Movie* movie);

    /*
    * will print the movie list of the crew member
    */
    void printMovies();
    void printMember();


    /*
     * constructor
     */
    CrewMember();
    CrewMember(string name, int id ,int age, char gender,
                        vector<Movie*>* movies, string jobDescription);

    void removeFromAllMovies();

    /*
     * destructor
     */
    virtual ~CrewMember();

    /*
     * getters
     */
    vector<Movie*>* getMovies() const;
    int getMoviesNumber() const;
    int getId() const;
    int getAge() const;
    string getName() const;
    string  getDescription() const;
};

#endif /* CREWMEMBER_H_ */
```

Comment: And you think this has nothing to do with `CrewMember`? Show its header.

Comment: I'd say that the error is `CrewSorter` is not defined. Probably a circular dependency in the two header files.

Comment: 1) How is `CrewMember` defined? 2) You don't need to include CrewMember.h if you are only using pointers in your class. You can forward-declare `class CrewMember`

Comment: added the crew member class to your request @LogicStuff

Comment: Why are you including and forward-declaring `Movie` ?

Comment: i'm using movie class in the crew member class @kchoose2

Comment: I suppose `Movie.h` includes `CrewMember.h`?

Comment: Off topic: Lot of pointer action going on there you might want to think about reducing. For example, vector of pointer is usually over complicating things.

Comment: Since `CrewMember` is only used as a pointer in the header, it should be sufficient to declare the class and remove the header: try whether that solves _this_ problem. If so it would imply that you got a cyclic dependency in your header files (e.g., `<Movie.h>` including `SmallToBitIdSort.h`).

Comment: Off topic but you never want to have `using namespace std;` in a header file.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you will need to remove the `#include "Movie.h"` from CrewMember.h as part of cleaning up the circular include problem.  Whatever consequences there might be from removing that include can be dealt with in some way that doesn't create a circular problem.

Comment: Ryan, I suspect @kchoose2 's point is you are including and forward declaring. You shouldn't need to do both, and if you do, something funny is going on that needs another look.

Comment: when removing the "include movie" i get another error that movie is not declared

Comment: Better post movie.h as well then.

Comment: On what line where do you get the error that movie is not declared?  I hope you still predeclared `Movie` in Cremember.h so it is an incomplete type, not an undeclared type.  If the error is that it is incomplete, we need some details of which line caused that to tell you what code to move or change to fix it.

Comment: @Ryan Try moving `#include "Movie.h"` to the `.cpp` file.

Comment: @LogicStuff that solved all the problems! thanks a lot!

Comment: But do you know why?

Comment: yes, you guys made it pretty clear, the circular definitions from movie to crew member,isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

In your CrewSorter and SmallToBigIdSorter, you only use a `CrewMember*` -- so you can get away with just forward declaration in the header files (both sorter classes).

```
class CrewMember;

class SmallToBigIdSorter : public CrewSorter {
// ...
```

Then in the .cpp files, `#include "CrewMember.h"` so it knows the actual implementation.